# Error: Cannot find module '@heroku/buildpack-registry'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

I am trying to deploy a web app on Heroku. I am getting the following error
`Error: Cannot find module '@heroku/buildpack-registry'`
I tried adding the version of node I am using but still didn't help.
I also upgraded Heroku using `npm i heroku@7.59.0` this too didn't help.
Any thoughts on this?

This is my package.json

```
{"name":"gssrDB",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.18.0"
  }
  ,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon index.js",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroku-cli/plugin-buildpacks": "^7.54.0",
    "@heroku/buildpack-registry": "^1.0.1",
    "async-file": "^2.0.2",
    "cli-ux": "^4.9.3",
    "dotenv": "^9.0.2",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "ejs-mate": "^3.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "got": "^8.3.2",
    "heroku": "^7.59.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.6",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.9",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.13",
    "phoenix": "^1.6.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

I solved it like this in terminal

```
$ heroku plugins:install buildpack-registry
$ heroku plugins:install buildpacks
```

may be it works

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem, and I solved it by using proper node version.
For the current heroku version, node16 works, otherwise it cause error in buildpack

Answer (score 0):

Two things helped in fixing this:

1. update the heroku CLI

   ```
   npm install -g heroku
   ```
2. Adding the engines in the package.json with the currently installed node and npm    versions

   ```
   "node": "14.18.0",
   "npm": "7.6.3"
   }
   ```