# laravel heroku Vite manifest not found at: /app/public/build/manifest.jso

Tags: laravel, npm, heroku, vite

after uploading my project Laravel in Heroku say "Vite manifest not found at: /app/public/build/manifest.json"

it work perfectly in localhost but in Heroku not working.

this is a preview of the problem

https://res.cloudinary.com/wanis4007/image/upload/v1656872417/Screenshot_2022-07-03_211622_ohzgs5.png

I run this code before push the project in Heroku

```
npm install
npm run dev
npm run build
```

any suggestion ?

Comment: Also read: [Vite manifest not found at: manifest.json in Laravel 9](https://devnote.in/vite-manifest-not-found-at-manifest-json-in-laravel-9/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay , the solution is to add both nodejs and php buildpacks to the project before deployment (you can do this also after deployment but you have to redeploy the project)

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/php
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs
```

and make sure you have the two buildpacks (php and node js) in your project by using this code

```
heroku buildpacks
```

note : you can add buildpacks with heroku dashboard in setting section

Comment: Hi Solayman Mousa, I got an error on adding the first module, which is heroku buildpacks:set heroku/app Error: Cannot find module '@heroku/buildpack-registry', can you help me resolve this? thanks

Answer (score 2):

I solved my code with this

`$ heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs` and
`$ heroku buildpacks`

after running this in my terminal, I adjusted my code and push to heroku again.
Note: The `--index 1` means nodejs build pack will run first before php. PHP Buildpack has already been reinstalled with laravel/heroku.
when you run

`heroku buildpacks`

it should give you the two buildpacks which is

```
$ heroku/nodejs and heroku/php
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed mine:

This solution is inspired by zneharks

```
$ heroku plugins:install buildpack-registry
$ heroku plugins:install buildpacks
```

[Solution of zneharks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69456585/error-cannot-find-module-heroku-buildpack-registry)

And I set nodejs

```
$ heroku buildpacks
```

Or

```
$ heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs
```